# Remove Selected Value in Dropdown List Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have an HTML list that I want to remove elements from as the user chooses. I've tried using this code from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript) but my issue seems to be accessing the element.
Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="ShipPlacement">
Ship:
<select name="shipSelec" id="shipSelec">
    <option value="aircraftCarrier">Aircraft Carrier</option>
    <option value="battleship">Battleship</option>
    <option value="cruiser">Cruiser</option>
    <option value="destroyer">Destroyer</option>
    <option value="destroyer">Destroyer</option>
    <option value="submarine">Submarine</option>
    <option value="submarine">Submarine</option>
</select>
<button type="button" onclick="placeShip()">Remove Selected Ship</button>
```

And here's my JavaScript:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   var shipList=document.getElementById('shipSelec');
});
function placeShip() {
  shipList.remove(shipList.options[shipList.selectedIndex].value;);
  shipList.remove(shipList.options[shipList.selectedIndex]);
  shipList.remove(shipList.options[selectedIndex]);
  shiplist.remove([shipList.selectedIndex])
}
```

I have several instances of the `remove()` method but that none of them work.
However, the best way I can convey my error to you is [through JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fqg56kaj/1).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you've jQuery loaded on the page, use it to bind events and remove element from DOM.

First, bind click event on the button using `click`. Use the `:selected` pseudo-selector to select the selected option from the dropdown and `remove()` to remove it from DOM.

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $('#shipSelec option:selected').remove();
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    $('#shipSelec option:selected').remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ShipPlacement">
  Ship:
  <select name="shipSelec" id="shipSelec">
    <option value="aircraftCarrier">Aircraft Carrier</option>
    <option value="battleship">Battleship</option>
    <option value="cruiser">Cruiser</option>
    <option value="destroyer">Destroyer</option>
    <option value="destroyer">Destroyer</option>
    <option value="submarine">Submarine</option>
    <option value="submarine">Submarine</option>
  </select>
  <button type="button">Remove Selected Ship</button>
</div>
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/yrygxtps/)

---

Note that there are several issues in your code

1. In [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fqg56kaj/1) "LOAD TYPE" option should be selected to "No Wrap".
2. jQuery is not included. This can be included using the "Frameworks & Extensions" option in the JavaScript tab
3. Syntax error in the first statement in the `placeShip()` near `.value;);`
4. `shipList` is local to the `ready` callback and hence not accessible from outside of it. Not even in `placeShip()`

---

With pure JavaScript

```
var shipList = document.getElementById('shipSelec');
shipList.options[shipList.selectedIndex].remove();
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/eLfcpomj/)

Comment: If you're curious, the reason I chose this is because you included a pure JavaScript solution. I did notice that I couldn't put `var shipList = document.getElementById('shipSelec');` into this function: `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {});` and expect it to work. If you're willing & able, could you explain why that is?

Comment: @Larrimus Please check [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/eLfcpomj/1/). Again, if you define a variable with `var` in a function, it is not accessible outside of that function. So, accessing the variable outside will give `undefined`. [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](//stackoverflow.com/q/500431) and to understand it deeply see [You don't know JS - Scope & Closures](https://escher.gitbooks.io/you-don-t-know-js-scope-closures/content/ch1.html) book.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#btn").click(function() {
  $("#shipSelec option:disabled").prop("disabled", false)
  $("#shipSelec option:selected").prop("disabled", true)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ShipPlacement">
  Ship:
  <select name="shipSelec" id="shipSelec">
    <option value="aircraftCarrier">Aircraft Carrier</option>
    <option value="battleship">Battleship</option>
    <option value="cruiser">Cruiser</option>
    <option value="destroyer">Destroyer</option>
    <option value="destroyer">Destroyer</option>
    <option value="submarine">Submarine</option>
    <option value="submarine">Submarine</option>
  </select>
  <button type="button" id="btn">Remove Selected Ship</button>
```

I suggest just disable the option not remove

Comment: [Disabling doesn't change the selected option](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/yrygxtps/1/), not what OP want. To overcome, you can select first non`:disabled` option.